# Convert array of hex numbers to a unsgined char* for Inline::C

Tags: c, arrays, perl, hex

I need to convert an array of hex numbers to a string, such that it can be passed to a C function (using Inline::C) as an unsigned char*, which then can be put into an array of bytes:

```
my @hex_vals = (0x06, 0x0D, 0x04, 0x16, 0x19, 0x0);
```

On the C side, function looks like this:

```
void takeMessage(unsigned char *message)
{
    unsigned char stuff[1088];
    stuff[0] = message[0];
    stuff[1] = message[1];
    ...
}
```

Got the Inline::C part working, just trying to pack the string.
Thanks

Comment: `@hex_vals` is a misnomer. There's nothing hex about the vals. Hex is a text/string representation of a number, but `@hex_vals` actually contains numbers. `@vals` would be more accurate (though equally vague) name.

Comment: I didn't intend to cause any confusion with the name. I originally had it called @arr and should have kept it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
takeMessage(pack 'C*', @hex_vals)
```

And on the XS side, I'd use

```
void takeMessage(SV* message_sv)
{
    STRLEN len;
    unsigned char* message_buf = (unsigned char*)SvPVbyte(message_sv, len);
    unsigned char stuff[1088];

    if (len > 1088)
        croak("...");

    Copy(message_buf, stuff, len, unsigned char);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent I didn't even think about using SV* and SvPVbyte.

Comment: `char*` arguments are broken. You lose the length and the UTF8 flag of the string. That means you can't handle binary data, and your code suffers from The Unicode Bug.